# Plotting SHP file R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, shapefile

Im trying to read and plot a shp file from Argentina to create a custom choropleth. Im following exactly all code examples to load and plot this map but nothing is working.

The R red sign stays on as like R is still processing information, but never plots anything or stops working.

This is my screen when I run to "plot" and then says Rstudio stopped working. Any idea why it could be not working?

[image]

Comment: Screenshots != code snippets. Please remove the image and make the effort to post the code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `ggplot2` seems to be able to handle this pretty well:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

arg_shp <- readOGR("../data/arg_adm/ARG_adm1.shp", "ARG_adm1")

arg_shp_map <- fortify(arg_shp)

gg <- ggplot() 
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=arg_shp_map, map=arg_shp_map, 
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + ggthemes::theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

Since you're using a GADM file, you don't really need to use an external shapefile tho, just use `getData()`:

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)

arg_adm <- getData('GADM', country='ARG', level=1)
arg_adm_map <- fortify(arg_adm)
```

(same `ggplot2` code from above works, just sub out the variable name).

I can't get the base plotting system to plot this either (on any graphics device). I think there are some complex polygons in part of the coastline. We can deal with that pretty easily tho:

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(magrittr)
library(sp)

arg_adm <- getData('GADM', country='ARG', level=1)

gSimplify(arg_adm, 0.01, topologyPreserve=TRUE) %>% 
  SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(dat=arg_adm@data) -> new_arg

plot(new_arg, lwd=0.25)
```

[image]

(base plot default margins and the way it deals with projections result in that different-sized map)

Unless you need the border precision, simplifying shapefiles like this can save a great deal of plotting time. You can use the optimized shape in `ggplot2` as well, along with an Argentina-tailored map projection:

```
new_arg_map <- fortify(new_arg)

gg <- ggplot() 
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=new_arg_map, map=new_arg_map, 
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + ggalt::coord_proj("+proj=aeqd +lat_0=-37.869859624840764 +lon_0=-66.533203125")
gg <- gg + ggthemes::theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

(Though, `coord_map()`'s default Mercator projection is pbly gd enough for most uses)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort, you realle have helped me a lot. I have one question though as im making a choropleth with this map, and when I load just boundaries like your plots works fine. but when I try to add some data , takes ages to load (5min) before it plots the graphic. Im using this code  puntos <- read.csv("puntos.csv", sep = ",", header = T) puntos$Provincia <- as.factor(puntos$Provincia)
arg_pv <- fortify(arg_shp, region = "NAME_1") ggplot() + geom_map(data = puntos, aes(map_id = Provincia, fill = Puntos), map = arg_pv) + expand_limits(x = arg_pv$long, y = arg_pv$lat)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is posible to read a shp using maptools, but its support is limited. Have you tried reading it using `rgdal::readOGR(dir, layer)`?

The Environment window shows that you have a 'Large' object, but how large is it? if the shapes are the national or statal borders there should be no problem, but if you have all the roads or all the blocks of the country in the shape the things change.

Try using a unit test: try to plot the international border or the statal borders. If you can do that, the problem would be the size of the shapes.

PD: reebot your computer and try again, it could help if Rstudio it is the only programm running.